# How to recover restricted Google Play Console Account (verification failure)?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play-console, developer-tools

I recently created a developer account and encountered an issue during the verification process. I had used my brother's card for the payment, and mistakenly, I entered my own details instead of the cardholder's information during the verification process. After two failed attempts, I realized the mistake and attempted to verify using my brother's documents. However, despite multiple tries, the system is not accepting the verification.

Now, my developer account is restricted, and I haven't been able to perform any actions on the platform. I want to highlight that all the details provided were correct, and the payment was successfully made.

Here are my questions:

How can I resolve the verification issue and lift the restriction on my account?
Is there a specific process or additional steps I need to follow to rectify this situation?
Is there a support team or contact point I can reach out to for direct assistance?
I appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this matter promptly. Thank you in advance for your help!

I did not even used a single thing and paid the fee.

Here is my appeal.

We've sent our decision to the account owner (abhishekgupta0118@gmail.com), and any additional email addresses provided when the appeal was submitted
Status
Appeal reply sent
Ticket number
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Submitted
24 Nov 2023, 22:07by abhishekgupta0118@gmail.com
Appeal details
I paid fee from by brother's card and initially I tried to provide my PAN details. But at last I gave PAN details and all the other details exactly similar to the Cardholder. Still I have PAN card image and Addhar Card too. But I don't know why you were not accepting. Card Holder name is Rahul Gupta and Other details were mentioned on provided field. Still you restricted. Please Accept the verification. I am a regular google products enthusiast. Please Accept the Appeal.
Additional email addresses

Appeal language
English

Comment: You used someone else's credit card. Part of the verification process is to verify you and possibly your trustworthiness. You failed that process. Remember, most credit cards have an identity feature - e.g. don't use another person's card (except for business accounts). Regarding the fee. You pay that no matter if you are approved or not. You might try again, pay the fee using your credit card, and use the correct payment and identity documentation.

Comment: Sir, I used my brother's Debit Card and at last I verified his identity too.  I mean , I don't own a card. I am student what should I do. I have to make Developer Account from my brother's email.

Comment: any updates I literally wrote a response

Comment: I understand what you did, but you cannot do that when you are accepting contracts and agreements. Suggestion: have your brother create the Google Play account and then add you to that account as a developer. That is supported for business accounts, but I am not sure for personal accounts.

Comment: I just confirmed that you can invite additional users to personal accounts. My suggestion is to create a new application under your brother's name and have him add you to the account once approved.

Answer (score 0):

scroll down to the bottom of the page.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en#topic=3450769

the 2nd link matches your issue

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9023898?hl=en&sjid=466755969858576259-EU

what you can do is contacting the developers support in the link or just go back and forth in the emails till its solved.